# Debian packaging Control File with specific version

Tags: debian

I have the following control file:

```
Source: tps-config
Section: cyber
Priority: optional
Maintainer: admin <admin@tps.cyber.local>
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 8.0.0), devscripts, dos2unix, dh-apparmor, config-package-dev (>= 5.0), python-yaml, python-tox
Standards-Version: 3.9.4
```

In the "build-depends" part, I want to add a specific version for python-tox. What is the correct syntax for this?

```
Build-Depends: python-tox(== 3.14.0)
```

I would think it's the above, however I'm not sure if it's `==` or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the authoritative [Debian policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#syntax-of-relationship-fields) says on the topic:

> The relations allowed are <<, <=, =, >= and >> for strictly earlier, earlier or equal, exactly equal, later or equal and strictly later, respectively.

You should however think twice whether you really want such a strict versioned dependency.
E.g. a package will usually have a version in the form `<upstreamversion>-<debianrevision>` (e.g. `3.14.0-1`); however the string with or without the *debianrevision* will not compare to equality, that is (according to `dpkg --compare-versions`): `3.14.0 << 3.14.0-1`.
OTOH, you probably don't want to pin your build-dependency on a specific debian revision. So you might be better of with specifying a version-range:

```
Build-Depends: foo (>= 1.2.3), foo (<2),
```

Apart from that: the debian/control snippet you give us has some severe problems:

- there's no section `cyber`
- the maintainer-address is dysfunctional
- the current recommended debhlper compat is `12`
- the current standards-version is `4.4.1`
- `python-tox` is no longer in Debian
- `python-tox` would not be a *native* package, and therefore must have a `<debianrevision>` suffix in the version-string
- Python2 is currently being purged

(that's 7 problems in 6 lines)